# How to create or use a Virtual Printer ready. I want it to print it it sends the file via web service

Tags: c#, web-services, driver

I have a need to create a virtual printer that will take the file (probably pdf) and send via webservices, but I have no idea how to create a virtual printer, I already analyze some codes like "colorpilot.com" or "printerplusplus" and even So you can not understand how to create or interact.

Explaining a bit more: So I need a user to press "Print", a virtual printer appears that will trigger my code with Webservices and send me some metadata. On the happier way I could put the code inside that virtual printer

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: I searched a lot and the closest I found was the printer ++, but unfortunately the manuals and codes do not work